# RecyclerView LinearLayoutManager - How to block scrolling at a certain position?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a list of items which is displayed in a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager`.
Now i would like to programmatically "freeze" the scrolling at a certain position so that the user can not manually scroll anymore.

I can scroll to a certain position using `linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(position);`

**EDIT:** it should freeze on the bottom, so the user can not scroll down. scrolling up is fine, but scrolling down must be restricted.

How can i disable the scrolling or at least that the user can not scroll further than the given position?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify if specified position is supposed to freeze on the bottom (so nothing after it is visible) or on the top (so it doesn't leave the screen)?

Comment: of course, it should freeze on the bottom, so the user can not scroll down. scrolling up is fine, but scrolling down must be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to make it work. But here's my suggestion:

1. you should override your `LinearLayoutManager`:

```
 linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
   @Override
   public boolean canScrollVertically() {
     return isScrollable(); // your custom method
   }
 };
```

2. listen to your scrolling event to determine scrolling up/down event:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    if (dy > 0) {
        // Scrolling up
    } else {
        // Scrolling down
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
        // Do something
    } else if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

});

3. Using `linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` to check if it's the threshold position and it's scroll down in `isScrollable()` to enable/disable srolling.